# python: is there a disadvantage to from package import * besides namespace collision

Tags: python, namespaces, import

I'm creating a class to extend a package, and prior to class instantiation I don't know which subset of the package's namespace I need.  I've been careful about avoiding namespace conflicts in *my* code, so, does

```
from package import *
```

create problems besides name conflicts?

Is it better to examine the class's input and import only the names I need (at runtime) in the `__init__` ??

Can python import from a set [] ?

does

```
for name in [namespace,namespace]:
    from package import name
```

make any sense?

I hope this question doesn't seem like unnecessary hand-ringing, i'm just super new to python and don't want to do the *one thing* every 'beginnger's guide' says not to do (from pkg import * ) unless I'm sure there's no alternative.

thoughts, advice welcome.

Comment: Can you explain/show why you won't know what parts you have to import until runtime? As for the importing from a set, you can do something like this: `module = __import__('some_module')`. That is the equivalent to `import some_module as module`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order:

- It does not create other problems - however, name conflicts can be much more of a problem than you'd expect.
- Definitely defer your imports if you can. Even though Python variable scoping is simplistic, you also gain the benefit of not having to import the module if the functionality that needs it never gets called.
- I don't know what you mean. Square brackets are used to make lists, not sets. You can import multiple names from a module in one line - just use a comma-delimited list:

  ```
  from awesome_module import spam, ham, eggs, baked_beans
  # awesome_module defines lots of other names, but they aren't pulled in.
  ```
- No, that won't do what you want - `name` is an identifier, and as such, each time through the loop the code will attempt to import the name `name`, and not the name that corresponds to the string referred to by the `name` variable.

However, you **can** get this kind of "dynamic import" effect, using the `__import__` function. Consult the documentation for more information, and make sure you have a real reason for using it first. We get into some pretty advanced uses of the language here pretty quickly, and it usually isn't as necessary as it first appears. Don't get too clever. We hates them tricksy hobbitses.

Answer (score 2):

When importing * you get everything in the module dumped straight into your namespace. This is not always a good thing as you could accentually overwrite something like;

```
from time import *
sleep = None
```

This would render the time.sleep function useless...

The other way of taking functions, variables and classes from a module would be saying

```
from time import sleep
```

This is a nicer way but often the best way is to just import the module and reference the module directly like

```
import time
time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Note that neither `from time import *` nor `from time import sleep` allow you to break another module by doing `sleep = None`. `import time; time.sleep = None` *will* break other modules though. This is because Python treats assignment of bare identifiers different from assigning an object (which inclued modules) properties.

Comment: Well I meant break in the respect that if you later assign something to sleep but try to call it there will be a TypeError

Comment: I realize that you were talking about breaking your own module. I just added a bit of trivia :)

Answer (score 0):

you can import like `from PIL import Image, ImageDraw`

what is imported by `from x import *` is limited to the list `__all__` in x if it exists

importing at runtime if the module name isn't know or fixed in the code must be done with `__import__` but you shouldn't have to do that

Answer (score 0):

This syntax constructions help you to avoid any name collision:

```
from package import somename as another_name
import package as another_package_name
```